# sql - Raw data in a table and need to convert them into uniform data

Tags: sql

I have a table with raw data and need to change them into uniform data like

```
Rd - Road
St - Street
PL - Place
Dr- Drive
Ave - Avenue
```

and also way to find them for data clean up

[image]

Comment: Clue : Replace . Which database you are using ?

Comment: Microsoft sql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you mean

```
create table info
(
 address varchar(200),

);

  insert into info values('XYZ rd');
  insert into info values('234 st ');
  insert into info values('bcda ');


  select 
  case 
  when address like '%rd%' then  replace (address,'rd','road') 
  when address like '%st%' then replace (address,'st','street') 
  else address end as address from info
```